# Trigger \addtocounter every frame (not slide!)

Tags: beamer, counters

I am trying to have Beamer automatically add to the notes the total time my presentation has been running. However, the counter seems to be triggered every slide, not every frame.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\newcounter{lessontime}
\newcounter{activitytime}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\setcounter{activitytime}{10}
\addtocounter{lessontime}{\value{activitytime}}
\only<1>{One}
\only<2>{Two}
\only<3>{Three}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\setcounter{activitytime}{5}
\addtocounter{lessontime}{\value{activitytime}}
Total time is \thelessontime. It should be 15.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In practice, `\thelessontime` is 35 (10*3+5), but I want it to be 15 (10+5).

Is there a way to trigger the `\addtocounter` once every **frame** instead of once every slide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of the `\beamer@slideinframe` counter you can confine you commands to the first slide:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\newcounter{lessontime}
\newcounter{activitytime}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtime}[1]{%
    \ifnum\the\beamer@slideinframe=1%
        \setcounter{activitytime}{#1}%
        \addtocounter{lessontime}{\value{activitytime}}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\addtime{10}%
\only<1>{One}
\only<2>{Two}
\only<3>{Three}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\addtime{5}%
Total time is \thelessontime. It should be 15.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this a lot! Although @Werner's solution works in itself,  this solution is better suited for what I need to so because it lets me echo `\theactivitytime`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should approach this differently. Instead of including the counter setting and addition as part of the `frame`, set it outside the `frame`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{lessontime}
\newcommand{\activitytime}[1]{\addtocounter{lessontime}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\activitytime{10}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \only<1>{One}
  \only<2>{Two}
  \only<3>{Three}
\end{frame}

\activitytime{5}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  Total time is \thelessontime. It should be 15.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Based on your example, I've simplified the input a little via a macro `\activitytime{<time>}`, which defaults to adding `<time>` to the counter `lessontime`.

Comment: The solution is effective. Doesn't exactly solve my problem because I also want to express `\theactivitytime` but it set me on the right path by suggesting that the `\addtocounter` may be placed outside of the `frame` environment.